# Как проверить, есть ли в строке символ USD?

Tags: php

Как проверить, есть ли в строке символ USD на PHP?

Comment: Нет, нет. если в строке cодержится текст "USD" то вернуть просто true

Comment: Нужен устойчивый вариант. такой у меня пропускал раз через раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$str = 'Цена 50$ за штуку';
if(strpos($str, '$') !== 0)
   echo 'Цена в баксах';
else
   echo 'Цена в чем угодно, но не в баксах';
```

Answer (score 1):

В первом ответе ошибочка, надо так:

```
$str = 'Цена 50$ за штуку';
if(strpos($str, '$') !== false)
   echo 'Цена в баксах';
else
   echo 'Цена в чем угодно, но не в баксах';
```

т.к. если знак доллара будет вначале строки (`$str = '$ Цена 50 за штуку';`) данный пример покажет что его нет, т.к. `strpos` вернет 0 (первый символ в строке)

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump((bool)preg_match("#(\\$)#",'Строка с символом $'));
```